# Ajax loading content replacement or content append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on an almost "all ajax website", content is requested on hashTag change.
and I am hesitating betwen 2 options :

*****1***********

On each request, the content is replaced.

*****2***********

Each time content is requested, a new div is appended to the content and previous content is hidden.

I can't use the cache on most parts of the website because of dynamic content

I would prefer option 2 because I can avoid reloading content when the client uses the back button of user but will the fact that a lot of content is hidden but present on the page after many requests afect the client's perfomances?

Is there some other reasons you are aware of that would make you choose option 1 or option 2?

Comment: You can also append the new and remove (not only hide) the current, can't you?

Comment: @JanZyka Other than potentially using different functions, how is that different to replacing the content?

Comment: @JanZyka yes but then I will have to reload the "already loded" content when client use back button on his browser

Comment: `I can't use the cache on most parts of the website because of dynamic content` - Because of that comment I don't see the point in keeping previously loaded content on the page when loading new content.  If the content is likely to change between loads then just go for option 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So option one in option 1 the content of the div is replaced and option 2 would have multiple divs on page shown or hidden depending on a hash tag.  They seem pretty much the same to me.  Both of those would initiate a css redraw/repaint.  I do not see an obvious reason to do one over the other.  My inclination would be to option one for the reason of not polluting your page with unneeded markup.  I wouldnt stress about this one.  My ultimate solution would be to start using a MV* library like Angular or Knockout as they have baked in functionality for data binding.

Comment: ok I'll have a look at those libraries.